# Hibernate Envers: Auditing with Embedded class in Composite Key

Tags: hibernate, jpa, composite-primary-key, hibernate-envers, embeddable

I am trying to activate auditing on a JPA entity with Hibernate Envers (curret version: 5.4.1.Final).

**Problem:** The entity has an composite key (`@EmbeddedId`) and the key class has an `@Embedded` class itself. I don't get `@Audit` to work.

**Question:** What causes the problem here and can you suggest a solution/workaround?

**Example:**
The database uses a concept of a common dataspace across all tables. A table `item` might have the columns: `dataspace1, dataspace2, dataspace3, itemid, value1, value2, ...`. Of course, an audit table `item_aud` is present as expected by Hibernate Envers.

I've got the following classes:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "item")
@Audited
public class Item {
    @EmbeddedId 
    private ItemKey itemKey;

    @Column(name = "value1")
    private String value1;

    @Column(name = "value2")
    private String value2;
    ...
}    

@Embeddable
public class ItemKey {
    @Embedded 
    private DataSpace dataSpace;

    @Column(name = "itemid")
    private String itemId;
}

@Embeddable
public class DataSpace {
    @Column(name = "dataspace1")
    private String dataSpace1;

    @Column(name = "dataspace2")
    private String dataSpace2;

    @Column(name = "dataspace3")
    private String dataSpace3;
}
```

With this setup I get an exception: `org.hibernate.MappingException: Type not supported: org.hibernate.type.ComponentType`

Saving/Loading entities works fine when `@Audit` is deactivated. It also works when I put the three `DataSpace` properties flat into `ItemKey`. Nevertheless, we would prefer a solution with a separate `DataSpace` class as it is shared among other entities.

Comment: Given your comments, it sounds like a bug unfortunately.

Comment: Indeed. In case this is a bug, we would appreciate any suggestion for a workaround :-)

Comment: Could `ItemKey` simply extend `DataSpace` (think you would need to add `@MappedSuperclass` to DataSpace in that case)?

Answer (score 0):

Given your comments it seems like a bug.

I think that extension rather composition should work however.

While the JPA specification does not explicitly mandate that extending an Embeddable class should be supported,  Hibernate *does* support this construct.

You should also be able to retain the get/set methods so no client code should have to change.

```
@MappedSuperclass
@Embeddable
public class DataSpace {
    @Column(name = "dataspace1")
    private String dataSpace1;

    @Column(name = "dataspace2")
    private String dataSpace2;

    @Column(name = "dataspace3")
    private String dataSpace3;
}

@Embeddable
public class ItemKey extends DataSpace {

    @Column(name = "itemkey")
    private String itemKey;

    public void setDataSpace(DataSpace dataSpace){
        //copy to the inherited fields
    }

    public DataSpace getDataSpace(){
        DataSpace dataSpace = new DataSpace();
        //populate form the inherited fields

        return dataSpace;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for suggesting this approach. It technically works! Unfortunately, we lose the possibility to get/set `DataSpace` instances, e.g., `myItem.getKey().setDataSpace(myDataSpace)`.

Comment: You can still have these methods. Just copy to the individual fields on set or return a new instance populated from the fields on get.